# Jest-Expo crashes on example (React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

I'm very confused on why the example test isn't running. I'm using Expo Web here with typescript. My frontend runs fine using `expo start --web`.

```js
// App.tsx
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
       <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I followed the example test from [the expo-jest docs](https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/)

```js
// App.test.js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from '../App'; // <-- only changed path to match my folder structure

describe('<App />', () => {
    it('has 1 child', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
        expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

However when I run `npm test`, I get

```
const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
                               ^
React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I know this is about mixing up default exports with named exports most of the time but I am cleary using a default export and import. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have `app.json` file in the directory which also contains `App.tsx`. Jest tries to import `app.json` rather than `App.tsx` by default.

Configure Jest's [moduleFileExtensions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulefileextensions-arraystring) and place `tsx` in the left.

```json
"moduleFileExtensions": ["tsx", ...]
```

Comment: Ideally the expo typescript jest setup works out of the box. For visibility here's the related expo docs PR: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/11580