# React native testing with Typescript and Jest

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to start test with react-native/expo and typescript. I have created an app with the expo's basic typescript template.

To start testing, I followed the expo's documentation on [testing with Jest](https://docs.expo.io/guides/testing-with-jest/). I have added `jest-expo` and `react-test-renderer` as dev dependencies, and have updated the `package.json` as per the docs:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    ...
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "^41.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the test, App.test.tsx:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import App from "../App";
import React from "react";

describe('<App />', () => {
    it('has 1 child', () => {
        const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
        expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

In the editor (Webstorm) it is throwing 2 errors:

1. `tree Object is possibly 'null'.`
2. `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactTestRendererJSON | ReactTestRendererJSON[]'.   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactTestRendererJSON[]'`.

And also, when I run the test, it throws a different error for `<App />`

> `renderer.create(<App />).toJSON()`:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Could you please help me what am I missing here. How to test react native with typescript and jest?

Comment: I got your last error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` too with TypeScript. It was trying to import app.json instead of my component. Perhaps my post could help you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549722/jest-expo-crashes-on-example-react-createelement-type-is-invalid-expected-a

Comment: @Kipnoedels Yup! Found this issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9541#issuecomment-693319666. Seems that is because of expo's bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like there's a bug/issue with Expo's Jest preset, as I found out  that there's an open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9541#issuecomment-693319666) related with the error.

To fix the issue as per the GitHub answer and like Kipnoedels has pointed out, I had to add this in my jest configuration of `package.json`:

```
"moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js"]
```

So, the `package.json` looks somewhat like this:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ..
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js"]
  }
}
```